# How do I change build settings of an Xcode project that is a git submodule

Tags: ios, git-submodules, workspace, projects

I have an Xcode project with an iOS app that uses another project, say Rest Kit, that is actually a Git submodule.

I want to effect a change in the build settings of RestKit, for good reason, when I build a debug build but at no other time. I don't want to modify the build settings itself because it may just be the one app I need to make the change for. And any change made will appear as a changed file in Git.

Comment: So you want to use git-submodules but you actually dont want to use git-submodules as you plan to modify things without letting them being distributed.

Comment: I want to use a git-submodule to provide the latest version of the code (e.g. RestKit). But I have no need to modify it. I'd still like to control what it builds without creating a changed state that could effect other projects also using the project.